# How can I mark <italic><bold><italic> (why doesn't `*italic***bold***italic*` work)?

Tags: support, markdown, markdown-rendering

I was able to put it all in the title:

How can I mark  (why doesn't `*italic***bold***italic*` work)?

It produces: *italic***bold***italic*

Is that a bug or just poor design?

Comment: See the last para of https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126386/248731

Comment: To me, this is a feature, not a bug. Making it harder to do formatting like that is a good thing, since such formatting is generally terrible to read. You can still do it if it is legitimately necessary, but it shouldn't be easy.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can nest emphasis and bold just fine, but without intervening spaces, the outermost style applies throughout and so you only need to *add* bold in the middle.

In other words, you have too many stars:

```
*italic**bold**italic*
```

renders as

*italic**bold**italic*

This is Rule 9 of the [CommonMark specification on emphasis and strong markup](https://spec.commonmark.org/0.28/#emphasis-and-strong-emphasis):

> Emphasis begins with a delimiter that can open emphasis and ends with a delimiter that can close emphasis, and that uses the same character (`_` or `*`) as the opening delimiter. The opening and closing delimiters must belong to separate delimiter runs. If one of the delimiters can both open and close emphasis, then the sum of the lengths of the delimiter runs containing the opening and closing delimiters must not be a multiple of 3.

`***` is a multiple of 3.

If you don't want to *nest* styles, but wanted to change style altogether, then you need to switch delimiters. Switching between `*` and `_` tells the parser that one style ended, and the other started, and avoids creating a delimiter run that's a multiple of 3.

So use one of these two forms:

```
*italic*__bold__*italic*
_italic_**bold**_italic_
```

which both render the same:

*italic***bold***italic*
*italic***bold***italic*

Comment: @ErikA: right, covered both options.

Answer (score 4):

You can alternate `_` with `*` (either use `_` for italic and `**` for bold, or `*` for italic and `__` for bold).

*s***o***m***e** *t***e***x***t**

which is defined as

```
_s_**o**_m_**e** *t*__e__*x*__t__
```

Comment: But the interactive tools (mark and click) seem not to know that trick ;-)